# Adobe Dreamweaver Copying code with color/style/formating etc

Tags: dreamweaver

Is there a way to copy the code with color/style/formating etc from a Adobe Dreamweaver into Microsoft Word document. Like Visual Studio, Eclipse, Notepad++ with NppExport plugin. For example:
[Eclipse](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/806x318q90/910/BPpkNi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I use to print the source code into pdf and then copy to word document (not a solution, but a workaround to show code highlighting in word)